# iOS Constraints Autogenerating From Nowhere

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoa, uiview

I am about to put my fist through my monitor.

I have a custom view that has a play button on the left and a record button on the right. This view is intended to be placed on the screen in such a way that the view stretches the full width of the screen. Except no matter what I do, the control only stretches about 60% of the width of the screen.

So the way I have it set up, the controller for the view is a view as well (it ends up being a view-within-a-view setup). I set the constraints on this parent view to the typical stuff (leading/trailing being up against the sides, top being 30 away from the previous element). When the containing view is initialized, I create an instance of the recording view and add it as a subview:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    guard let view = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("RecordingView", owner:self, options:nil)?.last as? UIView else { return }
    self.addSubview(view)
}
```

And that's pretty much it. I've tried setting:

```
self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
// AND/OR
view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

I've tried manually setting the subview's constraints:

```
child?.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.heightAnchor)
child?.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor)
child?.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor)
child?.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor)
```

I've tried clearing and resetting the constraints. I've tried deleting and re-adding the view. I've tried checking and unchecking Autoresize Subviews. At this point I am so out of ideas that I don't even know what sort of information I am supposed to supply in order to assist with the answer.

Fist. Monitor. Ow.

Comment: Your question includes code to create constraints (`child?.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.heightAnchor)`, etc. Do you also have code that **activates** those constraints?

Comment: When you place the custom view in a blank view controller, does it behave the way you want it to?

Comment: @robmayoff I tried adding `child?.updateConstraints()` and `child?.layoutSubviews()`, if that's what you mean. (To no avail.)

Comment: @slickdaddy I placed it in another place in my app and it seemed to work perfectly.

Comment: @Abion47 either add `.isActive = true` to each of your constraints or wrap them in the class method `NSLayoutConstraint.activate([ /* constraints go here */ ])`

Comment: @Abion47 since your constraints will be optional (due to optional chaining) I'd prefer first method

Comment: @DanKarbayev I changed the line to `child?.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.heightAnchor).isActive = true` (and same to the other lines) and it had no effect.

Comment: @Abion47 either here or on a GitHub gist, post your custom view and the parent view and the view controller that it's in so we can diagnose it better.

Comment: @Abion47 have you tried visual debugger in Xcode to check constraints  that you are getting on your views? https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/special_debugging_workflows.html

Comment: @DanKarbayev I have. I'm seeing the custom constraint that I've placed on it, but it looks like its being overridden by another constraint `view.width = RecordingView.width - 393 @ 1000`, and another constraint that says `view.midX = RecordingView.midX - 196.5`. Neither of these constraints exist anywhere else in my project.

Comment: @DanKarbayev A combination of your `NSLayoutConstraint.activate` suggestion and using `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` seemed to do the trick. Thanks for the push in the right direction. :)

Comment: @Abion47 yeah, I wast just going to suggest to recheck if you have `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` turned off since those constraints you've mentioned above looks like autogenerated ones.